# How to handle error message if button gets pressed in selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hi I have button which tells if the phone number is used in Yahoo mail
But i want to make a program which checks if number in yahoo button will be clicked and redirected, but if number does not exist it will

```
driver.get("https://login.yahoo.com/?.lang=en-US&src=homepage&.done=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.com%2F&pspid=2023538075&activity=ybar-signin")

lol=0
log_in_btn= driver.find_element_by_id("login-username")
error= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='username-error']")
log_in_btn.send_keys(new_list[lol])

btn= driver.find_element_by_id("login-signin").click()

print(error.text
```

this is not working i dont know why

the site is https://login.yahoo.com/?.lang=en-US&src=homepage&.done=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.com%2F&pspid=2023538075&activity=ybar-signin

this is picture of what happens if number exist
[image]

[image]

and if it does not then this what the page looks like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to verify if

```
Sorry, we don't recognize this phone number.
```

message is occurred or not.

this css :

```
p[data-error]
```

represent error message.

**code :**

```
try:
   if len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("p[data-error]")) > 0 :
       print("Error is present and the messgae is ", driver.find_element_by_css_selector("p[data-error]").text)
   else:
       print("No error msg found")
except:
    print("There an issue, please check the code again.")
    pass
```